Elementor Form : client side javascript validation
I already did server side data validation using the hook elementor_pro/forms/validation and it's working fine.
In addition I would like to do client side data validation before submitting the form to fix invalid data straight away avoiding a round trip to the server.
I would like to do custom validation using Javascript and not using the default browser tooltip bubble.
I added this code and the validation works fine, errors messages are displayed on the form. However the form is still submitted when fields input are invalid.
document.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  // this is my custom validation function
  validateForm(e);
})

How to prevent the form being submit? preventDefault() function doesn't work as the form submit is done via AJAX.
I would like to know what's the correct way to stop the form submitting when the client side validation failed.

One solution would be to disable the submit button by default, validate the form on input change and enable the submit button IF everything is valid. Ofc...this is client-side validation and can be easlily bypassed

When does the ajax call happen? Your validateForm() function doesn't save its return value (if any) to a variable, so the submit listener doesn't know if the form is valid or not.

Thanks to your solution Mihai T, I managed to do it :
By changing the type of the button to « button », so it won’t submit the form.
btn.setAttribute("type", "button");

Then adding an listener to the button for click event.
btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    validateForm(e);
});

When all inputs (3 in my case : email, tel, text) are correct, set back the type to « submit » for the button.
function validateForm(e) {
    if (isEmailValid() && isTelValid() && isTextValid()) {
        btn.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    } else {
        //add error messages to UI
    }

